# Three.js - Updated geometry is not rendering changes

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm having a little issue here. I have a `THREE.Line` object, with a material and a geometry. The init method pushes 2 vertices to the geometry, add the Line to the scene, the line is rendered just fine.

But I have an event listener... Every click in the canvas will add another vertex. But when the scene is rendered, only the original 2 vertices are rendered. I've output a dump of `scene.children` and I'm sure that the Line is in the scene, and the geometry has changed.

In the documentation it says something about applying:

```
geometry.dynamic = true
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
```

But these didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried rerunning any of the `compute` methods? http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/52/#Reference/Core/Geometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the three.js Wiki: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

> You can only update content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers
>   (this is very costly, basically equivalent to creating new geometry).
>
> You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating larger buffer and then
>   keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden.

Geometries are specified via vertex buffer objects, which have fixed sizes. You can create and delete buffers, but you cannot resize them.

As a workaround, you could create a geometry with extra vertices and collapse the unwanted ones into a single point.

three.js r.52

---

EDIT: A newer approach is described in [Drawing a line with three.js dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically/31411794#31411794).

Comment: What the heck. Does the size of a buffer = the number of points it has? how is size of buffer relevant here?

Comment: What's the best way to keep unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden? Since vertices don't have individual `visible` properties, nor individual alpha coloring, do they just need to be strategically positioned over another vertex?

Comment: A more elegant solution is there with r72 now - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31411794/1027058