# Drawing a line with three.js dynamically

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

This is what I'd like to achieve (a modifiable polygon where the red circles are vertices) and I'd like to build the polygon dynamically.

[image]

When initiating the geometry as

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(point);
geometry.vertices.push(point);

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({}));
```

it works well until the second click, it builds a straight line between 1 and 2 but does not add a third line when it's pushed to the array. WebGL seems to require buffered points.

When I predefine vertices like this I can draw two lines (third click)

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    geometry.vertices.push(point);
}

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({}));
```

but this is not a good solution as I don't know how many vertices does the user want to add and it's pointless to assign it a big number as I have to loop it multiple times.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can animate a line -- or increase the number of points rendered -- very easily using `BufferGeometry` and the `setDrawRange()` method. You do need to set a maximum number of points, however.

```js
const MAX_POINTS = 500;

// geometry
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

// attributes
const positions = new Float32Array( MAX_POINTS * 3 ); // 3 vertices per point
geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );

// drawcalls
drawCount = 2; // draw the first 2 points, only
geometry.setDrawRange( 0, drawCount );

// material
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

// line
line = new THREE.Line( geometry,  material );
scene.add( line );
```

If you want to change the *number of points rendered* after the first render, do this:

```js
line.geometry.setDrawRange( 0, newValue );
```

If you want to change the *position data values* after the first render, you set the `needsUpdate` flag like so:

```js
line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true; // required after the first render
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z34cfhkj/) showing an animated line which you can adapt to your use case.

three.js r.147

Comment: `MAX_POINTS = 500;` means that if the user creates more than 500 points it breaks down, correct?

Best case scenario would be that I do not have to predefine how many points I want to add. Although your solution is still better than mine since `BufferGeometry` is more memory efficient and you use less draw calls.

Comment: This is how to do what you want within the framework of three.js.

Comment: @WestLangley Can this be adapted to use the LineDashedMaterial?, I want to do something simiar but with dashes, I will open a question if feasible.

Comment: @Neil Yes. You would have to add an additional geometry attribute `lineDistance` to accommodate `LineDashedMaterial`.

Comment: why didn't you just paste the link to the original post?
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

Comment: I wouldn't allocate 500 points up-front, then worry if it was enough ...
Instead, I'd do it in smaller BufferGeometry chunks, say 100 points each. Once you use-up all 100, you add another BufferGeometry for another 100 points and another Line segment. This way, you can keep adding new points without any limits.

Comment: How does this code example answer the question?  The OP was looking for user-interaction.  The code only shows how to to RENDER a line; not draw & edit one.  Asking for a friend!!

Answer (score 13):

### Draw a line in real time

**[Here an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/a21ey9y6/)** where I optimized the code from **user3325025** his example; In this case there is absolutely no need to update all the points of the line on render. Update is only needed `onMouseMove` (updating end of line) and `onMouseDown` (drawing new point):

```
// update line
function updateLine() {
  positions[count * 3 - 3] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 - 2] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 - 1] = mouse.z;
  line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

// mouse move handler
function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  mouse.z = 0;
  mouse.unproject(camera);
  if( count !== 0 ){
    updateLine();
  }
}

// add point
function addPoint(event){
  positions[count * 3 + 0] = mouse.x;
  positions[count * 3 + 1] = mouse.y;
  positions[count * 3 + 2] = mouse.z;
  count++;
  line.geometry.setDrawRange(0, count);
  updateLine();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I updated the fiddle with mouse events and a vector array if you want to scribble freehand.

https://jsfiddle.net/w67tzfhx/40/

```
function onMouseDown(evt) {

    if(evt.which == 3) return;


    var x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    var y =  - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // do not register if right mouse button is pressed.

    var vNow = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0);
    vNow.unproject(camera);
    console.log(vNow.x + " " + vNow.y+  " " + vNow.z); 
    splineArray.push(vNow);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove",onMouseMove,false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup",onMouseUp,false);
}
```