# spline curve with steady transition in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js, bezier, cubic-spline

I am drawing a CubicBezierCurve3 curve in three js. However, I would like it to be drawn part-by-part with a steady transition, instead of the entire curve being drawn at once. You may visualize it as a moving rocket leaving behind a gas trail.

**My idea was the following**

1. Find all the points that form the CubicBezierCurve3, and save in a variable called 'allpoints'. Assume we have found exactly 50 points in the CubicBezierCurve3 as shown below

   ```
   var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
           new THREE.Vector3( -5, 0, 20 ),
           new THREE.Vector3(0, 15, 0 ),
           new THREE.Vector3(0, 15, 0 ),
           new THREE.Vector3( 2, 0, -10 )
   );

   geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints( 50 );
   allpoints = geometry.vertices;
   ```
2. At each iteration, plot 10 points, which means

> Iteration 0 : plots points 0 to 9 Iteration 1 : plots points 10 to 19
>   Iteration 2 : plots points 20 to 29 Iteration 3 : plots points 30 to
>   39 Iteration 4 : plots points 40 to 49

This function takes care of plotting 10 points at every iteration, Since we have 50 points, we can call cancelAnimationFrame at the end of the 5th iteration. The function contains some work-arounds, to take care of the timing.(Only after every 10 iterations, I plot the 10-points sequence, otherwise, the transition would be too fast, and we wouldn't be able to make out the difference)

```
 function drawPointCloud() {
        //scene.remove(dot);
        //scene.remove(dotsequence);
        //renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);

        console.log("inside drawPointCloud,count== "+count)

        if(count == 50)
        {
            console.log("stopped.")
            cancelAnimationFrame(animationTracker);
            return;
        }

        if(count%10 == 0)
        {
            var tempcount = count;

            count /= 10;
            var first = 10*count;
            var last = 10*(count + 1);
            console.log("inside drawPointCloud, count=="+count+"first=="+first+"last=="+last)
            console.log(allpoints[first])
            console.log(allpoints[last])
            var dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var dotMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 5, sizeAttenuation: false } );
            for(var i = first;i<last;i++)
            {
                dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( allpoints[i].x, allpoints[i].y, allpoints[i].z));
            }

            scene.remove(dotsequence);
            dotsequence = new THREE.PointCloud( dotGeometry, dotMaterial );
            scene.add( dotsequence );
            count = tempcount;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            camera.position.z -= 0.1;
            camera.position.y -= 0.1;
        }

        count++;
        animationTracker = requestAnimationFrame(drawPointCloud);
    }
```

**JS Fiddles**

1. Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7zp4/216/#) of the smooth transition that I have tried
2. Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7zp4/222/#) of all points in the CubicBezierCurve3

My question is, is there a better way/API to achieve this? Also, I would like to give the points a bit of a delay before turning off, like how an LED gets off instead of becoming invisible abruptly. Actually, it doesn't even have to be done by making use of individual points, as I have tried, I'm looking for anything that incrementally draws parts of a given cubic bezier curve.

**[image: An example of an expected output is here]**

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically/31411794#31411794 helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using particle system with **[the `THREE.GPUParticleSystem` plugin](http://threejs.org/examples/js/GPUParticleSystem.js)** like shown in [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpu_particle_system).

It already reminded me of a *"gas trail"* of a rocket...