# three.js lines does not update

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, vertices

I'm using three.js. And line is not updated. I want to lengthen this line in realtime.

- I think, first, A line is drawn by reading the two data.
- Second, Scene and clear.
- Third, reading the third information and the extended line.
- Fourth, Scene and clear.
- Finally line is longer in realtime.

But, this line is not generated.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial ({color : 0x0100FF, linewidth : 6});
function line_(k){
            if(k-1 >= 0){
                geometry.vertices.push (new THREE.Vector3 (py[k]*API.Orbit_Scale ,pz[k]*API.Orbit_Scale ,px[k]*API.Orbit_Scale));
            }
            else{
                geometry.vertices.push (new THREE.Vector3 (0,0,0));
            }
            line = new THREE.Line (geometry, material);
            line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            scene.add (line);
        }

function animate(){
            onWindowResize();
            line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            scene.remove(line);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `THREE.Geometry` instance you can update **the position** of existing vertices in the array and use `verticesNeedUpdate` to animate a line. You **cannot add vertices** to an existing line and expect `verticesNeedUpdate` to draw your new line with the added vertices.

The easiest solution to add vertices to an existing line geometry is:

- remove old line from scene
- create new line with extra vertices
- add line to scene

You can also tie this to an animation loop.

---

If you want to animate without removing/adding the geometry you have to use a  use a `THREE.BufferGeometry` instance with `drawCalls` instead. How to do that you can read **[here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31411794/1697459)**