# How to render a subset of non-indexed BufferedGeometry?

Tags: three.js

I am dealing with a non-indexed *BufferedGeometry*. I want to re-use the same *BufferedGeometry* to once per frame:

1. Render the entire buffer
2. Render a subset of the buffer (for example, first 120 vertices)

I tried to use `.addDrawCall(start, count)`, for which I got the following error:

> THREE.BufferGeometry: .addDrawCall() is now .addGroup().

Seeing as `.addGroup(start, count)` uses a similar signature, I changed to it, but to no effect.

---

**Edit**: I just noticed this paragraph regarding `.drawcalls` array, which means this functionality is not available for me:

> For geometries that use **indexed triangles**, this Array can be used to split the object into multiple WebGL draw calls.

---

Any way to achieve my goal using *BufferedGeometry*?

three.js r76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a subset of the vertices of non-indexed `BufferGeometry` use this pattern:

```
geometry.setDrawRange( startVertex, numVerticesToDraw );
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31411794) for related information and a live demo:

three.js r.76