# Adding & removing vertices from THREE.LineSegment

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've got a `THREE.LineSegments` object, and I want to change the number of vertices dynamically. When I modify the geometry vertices array, though, any lines with vertices that were removed just stay put.

Is there a way to remove vertices after the geometry has been created?

e.g., Below I'm taking a `LineSegments` object with 3 segments, and trying to change it later to have only 2 segments. The last line segment remains.

```js
var scene,
    renderer,
    camera;

var line;

initScene();
initLine();

setInterval(update, 500);


function initScene() {

  camera   = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000),
  scene    = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

  camera.position.z = 5;
  scene.add(camera);

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function initLine() {

  var verts = [
    randomV3(),
    randomV3(),
    randomV3(),
    randomV3()
  ];

  var geom = new THREE.Geometry();

  geom.vertices = [
    verts[0], verts[1],
    verts[1], verts[2],
    verts[2], verts[3]
  ];

  line = new THREE.LineSegments(geom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff00ff,
    linewidth: 3
  }));

  scene.add(line);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function update() {

  var verts = [
    randomV3(),
    randomV3(),
    randomV3()
  ];

  line.geometry.vertices = [
    verts[0], verts[1],
    verts[1], verts[2]
  ];
  line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function randomV3() {
  return new THREE.Vector3(
    (Math.random() * 4) - 2,
    (Math.random() * 4) - 2,
    0
  )
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/103/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically

Answer (score 4):

One approach to solve this problem is to dispose the old geometry and then create a new one like so:

```
line.geometry.dispose();

line.geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

line.geometry.vertices = [
  verts[0], verts[1],
  verts[1], verts[2]
];
```

This approach is demonstrated in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcL8ayzv/). However, consider to use `THREE.BufferGeometry` in order to have a more future-proof solution (`THREE.Geometry` will not be renderable at some point anymore). Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcL8ayzv/1/) with the same code but with `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

Instead of disposing the geometry, you could also create a `THREE.BufferGeometry` with enough buffer space so it can represent the biggest line object in your application. This approach is necessary since you can't resize buffers, only update their contents. The details are explained in this guide:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

BTW: Setting `linewidth` has no effect when rendering line primitives in `three.js`. The always have the width of 1 pixel.

`three.js R103`

Comment: Thanks! I thought about disposing & recreating the geometry, but seemed a little clumsy. I like the `THREE.BufferGeometry` route, but using the `setDragRange` solution @WestLangley linked too.

Comment: I think your `linewidth` note may actually be a browser issue (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10357). It works as expected for me in macOS Safari, but not Chrome.

Comment: It's actually not recommended to set this parameter (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/lineWidth). This will not be fixed in Chrome or Firefox since "wide" lines are not a native primitive of any modern hardware. They require emulation in either the driver or the application. Because of this, you should render wide lines always as polygons.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks :-)